# Reveal.js: how to create a custom transition (not predefined) between two vertical sections without fadeout effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js, reveal.js

I am looking for a way to have a transition between two vertical sections that look like the one provided in fullpage.js: 
https://codepen.io/ehouarn-perret/pen/jprrqx?editors=0010

Currently, I have something almost similar except that the slide transition causes direct fadeout on the previous section:
https://codepen.io/ehouarn-perret/pen/ajVBzY?editors=0110

My JavaScript code:

```
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function getSectionColors(length) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var randomColor = getRandomColor();
    results.push(randomColor);
  }
  return results;
}

var sectionCount = 6;
var sectionColors = getSectionColors(sectionCount);

for (var i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
  var section = 
      "<section style='background-color: " + sectionColors[i] + ";'>" +
      "<div class='section-content'>" +
      "<h1>" + i + "</h1>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</section>";
  $('#sections').append(section);
}

Reveal.initialize({
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  progress: false,
  transition: 'slide',
  backgroundTransition: 'slide',
  mouseWheel: true,
});

console.log(Reveal.getScale());
```

and related Html:

```
<div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
        <section id="sections">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve something similar, a transition that stick the two sections when transitioning from one to another?